# Pagespeed score dropping day by day on wordpress website without modification

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed

I recently optimized a wordpress website to achieve ~85 score on the PageSpeed tool. That was a week ago, since then the score dropped progressively to ~20 without other modification than purging the cache. 
I'm posting this here because I'm new to this kind of website development and because I noticed that some concurrent website have dropped the same way.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing ?

I tried to purge the cache of the website and to de-minify and re-minify HTML, CSS and JS.

Here is the pagespeed test for my website : https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fidealtek.fr&tab=desktop

If anyone know why would the score keep dropping I would be extremely thankful !

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: There's no way for us to know why your score is dropping in comparison to previous scoring.  Also, page speed questions are off-topic for SO.  They have nothing to do with programming (you are not writing any code for us to help analyze / debug).

Comment: Sorry I thought it was ok because there is a pagespeed tag and it is suggested to ask here on the pagespeed website :/

Answer (score 0):

If this was today there was a bug in Page Speed, check again.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be the problem